# Custom file extension doesn't open

Tags: android, file, mime-types, intentfilter

Same questions asked before, I tested them all and non of them worked.
I write a serialize object in a file and I name like `575454.myCustomExe`
I want my app to just open `*.myCustomExe` and no more.

How I save files :

```java
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("MyAppFolder") , getId() + ".myCustomExe");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        file.createNewFile();
        }
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    out.writeObject(serializableObject);
    out.close();
```

My Intent filter :

```xml
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.ImportActivity">

            <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/ic_save"
                android:label="label"
                android:priority="1">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />    

                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\.myCustomExe"/>    

            </intent-filter>
```

I tried `<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.myCustomExe" />` too.

Answer (score 0):

File extensions are not used much on Android. Starting with Android Q, *files* are not used much on Android. There is no requirement for a `ContentProvider` to put a file-like extension on a `content` `Uri`. So, while what you have I think is correct technically, as you note, it will not work very well.

There is nothing much that you can do about this, since you cannot change the behavior of other apps.

If you wish to support common `Intent` actions like `ACTION_VIEW`, your best bet is to save the file in a common meta-format (e.g., JSON, XML) with a file extension that matches, then have your `<intent-filter>` filter on the corresponding MIME type. You will need to deal with the possibility that the user chooses a file that was not created by your app, though technically you needed to deal with that even with your custom extension.